# Cannot run Phar archives

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, phar

On a RHEL server I cannot seem to run PhpUnit. Here are examples as root to illustrate the steps that I've tried to install PhpUnit and how it does not run:

```
# wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
# chmod +x phpunit.phar
# ./phpunit --version

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'phar://phpunit-4.3.4.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php' (include_path='.:') in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 592
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. {closure}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0

# mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
# which phpunit
/usr/local/bin/phpunit

# phpunit --version

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'phar://phpunit-4.3.4.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php' (include_path='.:') in /usr/local/bin/phpunit on line 592
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. {closure}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0
```

It seems that PHP is choking on the `phar://` address format defined on line 13:

```
# cat /usr/local/bin/phpunit | awk 'NR==592'
          require __PHPUNIT_PHAR_ROOT__ . $classes[$class];

# cat /usr/local/bin/phpunit | grep -n __PHPUNIT_PHAR_ROOT__
13:define('__PHPUNIT_PHAR_ROOT__', 'phar://phpunit-4.3.4.phar');
592:          require __PHPUNIT_PHAR_ROOT__ . $classes[$class];
601:        print file_get_contents(__PHPUNIT_PHAR_ROOT__ . '/manifest.txt');
20811:        if (defined('__PHPUNIT_PHAR_ROOT__')) {
20812:            $prefix = __PHPUNIT_PHAR_ROOT__;
26020:        copy(__PHPUNIT_PHAR_ROOT__ . '/ca.pem', $caFile);
```

The server is RHEL 6.5:

```
# uname -a
Linux foobar 2.6.32-220.38.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 15 08:34:56 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# cat /etc/issue
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to just use PHPUnit from PEAR, which also would not run with this error:

```
[root@panthercrm ~]# /usr/bin/phpunit
PHP Warning:  require_once(File/Iterator/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/
Autoload.php on line 64
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. require() /usr/bin/phpunit:43
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'File/Iterator/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /usr/share/pear/PHPUni
t/Autoload.php on line 64
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. require() /usr/bin/phpunit:43
```

Adding the following line to `/etc/php.ini` resolved the issue for the PEAR version of PHPUnit:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/pear"
```