# Composer not working on Windows (WSL)

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Installing Composer and trying to run it does not seem to work on a php-fpm container when this container is running on Windows (Ubuntu bash / WSL).

However, it runs smoothly everywhere else.

```
username@docker-php:/var/www/project$ php composer.phar update                                                      


  [ErrorException]                                                                                                              
  include(phar:///var/www/project/composer.phar/vendor/composer/../../src/Composer/Command/RunScriptCommand.php   
  ): failed to open stream: phar error: Cannot open phar archive "/var/www/project/composer.phar" for reading
```

Also, running the command again results into a different error:

```
username@docker-php:/var/www/project$ php composer.phar update                                                      

Warning: include(phar:///var/www/project/composer.phar/vendor/composer/../../src/Composer/Util/Silencer.php): fail
ed to open stream: phar error: Cannot open phar archive "/var/www/project/composer.phar" for reading in phar:///va
r/www/project/composer.phar/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444                                           

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'phar:///var/www/project/composer.phar/vendor/composer/../../src/Composer/Util/
Silencer.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in phar:///var/www/project/composer.phar/vendor/
composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444                                                                                            

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Composer\Util\Silencer' not found in phar:///var/www/project/composer.phar/src
/Composer/Console/Application.php:71                                                                                            
Stack trace:                                                                                                                    
#0 phar:///var/www/project/composer.phar/bin/composer(58): Composer\Console\Application->__construct()            
#1 /var/www/project/composer.phar(24): require('phar:///var/www...')                                              
#2 {main}                                                                                                                       
  thrown in phar:///var/www/project/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php on line 71
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Does this work? https://stackoverflow.com/q/26718836

Comment: How did you install `composer.phar`?

Comment: `php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && php composer-setup.php` @fyrye

Answer (score 2):

Fixed installing `Composer` in a different way!

```
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
            && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/ \
            && ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```